# ElasticSearch Script Issue for UPDATE

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I am trying to update an array value with following script

```
POST /book/123/_update
{
"script": "foreach (item : ctx._source.BookAvailability) { if (item['BookPublishDate'] == publish_date) { item['Price'] = start_price;} }",
  "params": {
    "publish_date":"2016-09-09T12:00:00",
    "start_price": "123"}
}
```

However I am getting following error,

```
{
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingMethodException[No signature of method: a7119b66f45277239600593efdc39002b301e293.foreach() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap, a7119b66f45277239600593efdc39002b301e293$_run_closure1) values: [[item:[[Price:189.000, BookCategoryID:e62dcda3-579a-4936-902c-05e1bcc97e3e, ...], ...]], ...]\nPossible solutions: each(groovy.lang.Closure)]]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

And My Schema goes like this,

```
{
 "BookID" : "123",
 "BookName": "abcd",
 .
 .
 .
 "BookAvailability" : [
 {
  "BookCategoryID" : "e62dcda3-579a-4936-902c-05e1bcc97e3e",
  "Price": "189.00",
  "BookPublishDate": "2016-09-09T12:00:00"
  .
  .
  .
 }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script instead

```
ctx._source.BookAvailability.findAll { it['BookPublishDate'] == publish_date }.each { it['Price'] = start_price }
```

It first selects all elements whose `BookPublishDate` matches the `publish_date` argument and then it iterates over the matches and sets the `Price` to `start_price`.

Comment: No Luck Gets another error` {
   "error": "ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[failed to execute script]; nested: GroovyScriptExecutionException[MissingMethodException[No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.filter() is applicable for argument types: (0d80cd763af1def98f143ee0694cc84eaefbd1d8$_run_closure1) values: [0d80cd763af1def98f143ee0694cc84eaefbd1d8$_run_closure1@1f7f5c5]\nPossible solutions: clear(), size(), clear(), clear(), size(), first()]]; ",
   "status": 400
}`

Comment: Sorry, it's not `filter` it's `findAll`, my bad, I've updated my answer. (mixing too many languages at a time can ruin your health :)

Comment: Very nice, glad we figured it out.